# SearchView in ActionBar - Search unanswered

Tags: android, searchview

I've been developing an app with a list that is filled by a WEBSERVICE all right, until I implement the SearchView in ActionBar, Try implementing it as it says in this tutorial:

> [Http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-filter-recyclerview-using-searchview-in-toolbar.html](http://Http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-filter-recyclerview-using-searchview-in-toolbar.html)

Everything runs perfectly fine without any error, even the log that is put.

However it does not search, I enter the parameters and it does not make the search my adapter stays blank:

[image]

This is part of my search:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_form, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        //
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when expanded
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean  onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item){
                        adapter.setFilter(plazas);
                        return true;

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        try {

            ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada =filter(plazas,newText);
            adapter.setFilter(listaFiltrada);
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    private ArrayList<Plaza> filter(ArrayList<Plaza> plazas,String texto){
        ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            texto=texto.toLowerCase();
            for (Plaza plaza: plazas){
                String plaza2=plaza.getCodigoPlaza().toLowerCase();
                if (plaza2.contains(texto)){
                    listaFiltrada.add(plaza);
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaFiltrada;
    }
```

**Complete code MainFragment :**

```
    /**
 * Fragmento principal que contiene la lista de las metas
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    /*
    Etiqueta de depuracion
     */
    private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
    Adaptador del recycler view
     */
    private MetaAdapter adapter;

    /*
    Instancia global del recycler view
     */
    private RecyclerView lista;

    /*
    instancia global del administrador
     */
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;

    /*
    Instancia global del FAB
     */

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

     /*
    Instancia global para el refresh
     */
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    ArrayList<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza>();
    // private List<Plaza> items = new ArrayList<Plaza> ();

    //ArrayList<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza> ();



    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Habilitar al fragmento para contribuir en la action bar
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        lista = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
        lista.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Usar un administrador para LinearLayout
        lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        lista.setLayoutManager(lManager);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_main);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync(80);// in dips
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.DEFAULT);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                cargarAdaptador();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Cargar datos en el adaptador
        cargarAdaptador();

        return v;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_form, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        //
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when expanded
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean  onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item){
                        adapter.setFilter(plazas);
                        return true;

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        try {

            ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada =filter(plazas,newText);
            adapter.setFilter(listaFiltrada);
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    private ArrayList<Plaza> filter(ArrayList<Plaza> plazas,String texto){
        ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            texto=texto.toLowerCase();
            for (Plaza plaza: plazas){
                String plaza2=plaza.getCodigoPlaza().toLowerCase();
                if (plaza2.contains(texto)){
                    listaFiltrada.add(plaza);
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaFiltrada;
    }





    /**
     * Carga el adaptador con las metas obtenidas
     * en la respuesta
     */
    public void cargarAdaptador() {
        // Petición GET
        VolleySingleton.
                getInstance(getActivity()).
                addToRequestQueue(
                        new JsonObjectRequest(
                                Request.Method.GET,
                                Constantes.GET,
                                null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        // Procesar la respuesta Json
                                        procesarRespuesta(response);
                                    }
                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.toString());
                                    }
                                }

                        )
                );
    }

    /**
     * Interpreta los resultados de la respuesta y así
     * realizar las operaciones correspondientes
     *
     * @param response Objeto Json con la respuesta
     */
    private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            // Obtener atributo "estado"
            String estado = response.getString("estado");

            switch (estado) {
                case "1": // EXITO
                    // Obtener array "metas" Json
                    JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");
                    // Parsear con Gson
                    Plaza[] plazas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Plaza[].class);
                    // Inicializar adaptador
                    adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(plazas), getActivity());
                    // Setear adaptador a la lista
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                case "2": // FALLIDO
                    String mensaje2 = response.getString("mensaje");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            mensaje2,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

**Complete code MetaAdapter :**

```
/**
 * Adaptador del recycler view
 */
public class MetaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MetaAdapter.MetaViewHolder>
        implements ItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Lista de objetos {@link Meta} que representan la fuente de datos
     * de inflado
     */
    private List<Plaza> items;

    /*
    Contexto donde actua el recycler view
     */
    private Context context;


    public MetaAdapter(List<Plaza> items, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MetaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MetaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        switch(items.get(i).getEstado())
        {
            case "0":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("OCUPADO");
                break;
            case "1":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("VACANTE");
                break;
            case "2":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("RESERVADO");
                break;
            default:
                viewHolder.estado.setText("ERROR");
        }
        viewHolder.nivel.setText(items.get(i).getNivel());
        //viewHolder.estado.setText(items.get(i).getEstado());
        viewHolder.colegio.setText(items.get(i).getIe());
        viewHolder.especialidad.setText(items.get(i).getEspecialidad());
        viewHolder.codigo.setText(items.get(i).getCodigoPlaza());
    }


    /**
     * Sobrescritura del método de la interfaz {@link ItemClickListener}
     *
     * @param view     item actual
     * @param position posición del item actual
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        DetailActivity.launch(
                (Activity) context, items.get(position).getPlazaID());
    }


    public static class MetaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView nivel;
        public TextView estado;
        public TextView colegio;
        public TextView especialidad;
        public TextView codigo;
        public ItemClickListener listener;


        public MetaViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);
            nivel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nivel);
            estado = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estado);
            colegio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.colegio);
            especialidad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.especialidad);
            codigo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
            this.listener = listener;
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(List<Plaza> items){
        //items = new ArrayList<>();
        //items.addAll(plazas);
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.items=new ArrayList<>();
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

**Complete code Plaza :**

```
public class Plaza {
    /*
    Atributos
    */
    private String plazaID;
    private String codigoPlaza;
    private String ie;
    private String modalidad;
    private String especialidad;
    private String nivel;
    private String jornada;
    private String tipoVacante;
    private String motivoVacante;
    private String estado;
    private String latitud;
    private String longitud;

    public Plaza(String plazaID, String codigoPlaza, String ie, String modalidad, String especialidad, String nivel, String jornada, String tipoVacante, String motivoVacante, String estado,String latitud, String longitud) {
        this.plazaID = plazaID;
        this.codigoPlaza = codigoPlaza;
        this.ie = ie;
        this.modalidad = modalidad;
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
        this.nivel = nivel;
        this.jornada = jornada;
        this.tipoVacante = tipoVacante;
        this.motivoVacante = motivoVacante;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.latitud = motivoVacante;
        this.longitud = estado;
    }

    public String getPlazaID() {
        return plazaID;
    }

    public String getCodigoPlaza() {
        return codigoPlaza;
    }

    public String getIe() {
        return ie;
    }

    public String getModalidad() {
        return modalidad;
    }

    public String getEspecialidad() {
        return especialidad;
    }

    public String getNivel() {
        return nivel;
    }

    public String getJornada() {
        return jornada;
    }

    public String getTipoVacante() {
        return tipoVacante;
    }

    public String getMotivoVacante() {
        return motivoVacante;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public String getLatitud() {
        return latitud;
    }

    public String getLongitud() {
        return longitud;
    }
    /**
     * Compara los atributos de dos metas
     * @param plaza Meta externa
     * @return true si son iguales, false si hay cambios
     */
    public boolean compararCon(Plaza plaza) {
        return this.plazaID.compareTo(plaza.plazaID) == 0 &&
                this.codigoPlaza.compareTo(plaza.codigoPlaza) == 0 &&
                this.ie.compareTo(plaza.ie) == 0 &&
                this.modalidad.compareTo(plaza.modalidad) == 0 &&
                this.especialidad.compareTo(plaza.especialidad) == 0 &&
                this.nivel.compareTo(plaza.nivel) == 0 &&
                this.jornada.compareTo(plaza.jornada) == 0 &&
                this.tipoVacante.compareTo(plaza.tipoVacante) == 0 &&
                this.motivoVacante.compareTo(plaza.motivoVacante) == 0 &&
                this.estado.compareTo(plaza.estado) == 0 &&
                this.latitud.compareTo(plaza.latitud) == 0 &&
                this.longitud.compareTo(plaza.longitud) == 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post you Plaza class

Comment: is `Estoy en la clase onQueryTextChange` and   `Estoy en la clase setFilter` are getting printed in log?

Comment: @NitinMesta  Ok, It's right

Comment: @NileshDeokar YES

Comment: and what is returned by `model.getCodigoPlaza()` ? since you are performing search on this string make sure it is same as what are you typing

Comment: Does your getCodigoPlaza holds the number what you are searching ?

Comment: Yes, Remember that the load of the list I do it by wolley

Comment: Help me :c...,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the you have only declared and initialized empty arrayList and Not reinitializing it

```
ArrayList<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza>();
```

In your procesarRespuesta for case 1 add this line.

```
this.plazas=Arrays.asList(plazas)
```

after

```
Plaza[] plazas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Plaza[].class);
```